# Ouroborous vs Tendermint

Tags: proof-of-stake

What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of Ouroborus (a Proof of Stake system) vs Tendermint (a BFT system)?

Some high level advantages of Tendermint I've seen so far (though I might be totally incorrect) are:

1. instant finality
2. faster settlement
3. lower fees (?)

And some advantages for Ouroborus:

1. formally verified
2. built in yield mechanism for validators (through staking)

I'm obviously a total novice here and would love to learn more about the cryptographic, economic, computational, etc properties of both systems and how they compare. I'm especially curious about the relative downside/risks of each system.

Comment: This question may not be appropriate for this site in its current form.  It should have a Cardano focus and be specific enough to lead to fact based answers.  General questions such as how does Bitcoin compare to Ethereum are not well handled by any StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is such a broad question, I'll use this answer to collect info/data/ideas as I self educate.

### Advantages of Tendermint

1. fast finality
2. lower fees
3. fast settlement
4. the network and consensus layer is decoupled from the application layer

### Disadvantages of Tendermint

1. deterministic leader election - make DDoS attacks possible
2. validators much run Sentry nodes which makes the infra harder to maintain (can't run on just a raspberry pi)
3. Limited validator set (still have to learn more but it seems like there are some restrictions on who can become a validator)
4. if 1/3 of validators are dishonest, the system breaks
5. Results in Pareto like capital accumulation

### Advantages of Ouroborus

1. Formally verified
2. Anyone can be a validator
3. Validator software can run with just a raspberry pi (which I *think* isn't possible with Tendermint)
4. will have an isomorphic layer 2

### Disadvantages of Ouroborus

1. Can't bootstrap without a trusted entity (but I think the new Gensis paper will make PoS bootstrapping possible)
2. Slower block times
3. Slower finality
4. Results in Pareto like capital accumulation

Of course if anyone has more items to add to any of these lists (or has opinions on which should be removed) please comment and let me know!

EDIT: here's an interesting table comparing various PoS systems: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZhx4Ix9xwFEUZFTihc_MBQcI43TK3jEhBjobhpiZbo/edit#gid=0 (I added a comment to see if we can get ADA included in the list)